# Trouble adding package System.Data.Common

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.mac

I'm building a console project using Xamarin 6.1.1 on Mac OS X 10.11.6. 
[image]

I've attached a screenshot of my current installed packages. I've tried adding both System.Data.Common 4.0.0 and 4.1.0 all end up with the same error.
[image]

ERROR:
"Could not install package 'System.Data.Common 4.1.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author."

Any idea on how to resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: what type of project are you trying to install the package in?

Comment: This is a Xamarin console project. Apologize in advance I'm very new to Xamarin. Not sure if i'm answering your question correctly.

Comment: is it targeting 4.5?  A console project in Xamarin is really the same as one in Visual Studio.  It's only when you're targeting Android or iOS that the Xamarin pieces really come into play.

Comment: Yes, the target framwork is Mono / .NET 4.5. How can I build a Mac console project using the package System.Data.Common?

Comment: according to the nuget page that package targets 4.5.1

Comment: Thanks, I've changed the target to 4.5.1. If you post your answer, I'll accept it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the nuget page for [System.Data.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.Common/) lists the supported frameworks - for .NET you need to be sure your project targets 4.5.1